# C++ map invalid conversion from int to const LexType& (which is defined by myself in fact a int)

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I defined a map like this :

```
std::map<std::string,LexType> lexname_s = { { "PROGRAM" , PROGRAM}}
```

And a LexType, like this :

```
typedef enum 
{
    ENDFILE,    ERROR,
    PROGRAM,    PROCEDURE,  TYPE,   VAR,        IF,
} LexType;
```

In Visual Studio Code, it always shows error type when I touch it.

//
I add more details for what i said.
the line
`std::map<std::string,LexType> lexname_s = { { "PROGRAM" , PROGRAM}}`
show error . it seems i can't initialize it in this way.
I compile it in the gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC) in a cloud server which is centos7.
AND the error code shows below

````
                 from parse.cpp:1:
../utils.h:52:27: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘const LexType&’ [-fpermissive]
           {"ERROR", ERROR}};
                           ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_tree.h:61,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/map:60,
                 from ../globals.h:6,
                 from parse.h:4,
                 from parse.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/stl_pair.h:112:26: error:   initializing argument 2 of ‘constexpr std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(const _T1&, const _T2&) [with _T1 = const std::basic_string<char>; _T2 = LexType]’ [-fpermissive]
       _GLIBCXX_CONSTEXPR pair(const _T1& __a, const _T2& __b)```
````

Comment: `LexType` doesn't look like an `int` at all. What is it, actually? A `struct`, or an `enum`?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `when I touch it`? It shows an error only when you change it's definition or as soon as you use it. Also your code seems to compile fine with MSVC [here](https://godbolt.org/z/ojb9KzMdT) based off Visual Studio 16.9

Comment: Just a note, VS Code is a text editor and not the same as Visual Studio proper. It might be using msvc, or mingw, or a connection to WSL or a container or cloud instance to compile the code.

Comment: 1. is an enum in fact.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have a macro named `ERROR` anywhere, right?

Comment: Yeah I am sure that there isn't macro named ERROR

Comment: First try to use enum class it is recommended by the core guideline, and see if the error changes.
secondly the code in this question is not [reproducable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so you may have to show us the code at utils.h  line 52 and parse.cpp line 1

open an empty solution and add your code as little as it can be for simplification  then if it reproduced the error in your new solution post the code here

Comment: I question context of that initialization. Also, confusing statement in question: `const LexType& (which is defined by myself in fact a int)`. From code it's declared as enum. IF you tried to declare same thing differently in different modules because of circular dependency, your code is ill-formed.

Answer (score 0):

EOF(which shows in the map define) is a reserved a macro defined in stdio.h
it's the problem of it.
change the name will be ok.